# SSIS Variable SQL command for ADO.net source

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

While this seems like a basic problem, I've been ripping my hair out FOR DAYS trying to get an efficient solution to this.

I have a lookup table of values on a server that I read from and assemble into a string using a C# Script task. I write this string into a variable that I want to pass in as my WHERE parameters inside a large SQL query on a ADO.NET data source (from a different server which I only have read access to) in my data flow. For example, this string would just be something like

```
  ('Frank', 'John', 'Markus', 'Tom')
```

and I would append that as my WHERE clause. 
 I can't read from a variable directly for an ADO.NET data source AND I can't use the 'Expression' property to set my SQL either as my SQL query is over 4000 characters. I could use an Execute SQL Task to run my query, load the results into a recordset and I assume, then loop through the recordset but that's extremely inefficient.

What would be the best way to do this? My end goal is to put these results inside a table on the first server.

Comment: Insert your parameter values into a table, then write your query to pull its parameter values from that table.

Comment: I assemble my parameters from a table on a server that I have admin access to. The problem is that I need to execute the query on another server (that I only have read access to) using these parameters. Or are you suggesting that I make the script task inside the data flow?

Comment: Nope, what you thought is what I meant.

Comment: I hope I'm not misreading this, but how would I pass the result of that script task to my ADO.net data source query then?

Comment: can you ask admin of that server to prepare view using this long query which will shorten your query to `select * from viewName where col in ('Frank', 'John', 'Markus', 'Tom')`?

Comment: No, the first thing.  You would need to write your values into a table on that Server.  If you cannot write there, you'll need a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set up Script Component as source - variables and strings inside scripts can be longer than 4000 characters so you can fit your query inside.

Setup your component similar to this article: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11119/script-componentsource-part1.aspx
In this one you have example how to fetch data using `ExecuteReader` and put it to output of script component: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11124/ssis-script-component-as-source-adonet.aspx In this one you have instructions how to aquire connection properly: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2011/05/30/use-connections-properly-in-an-ssis-script-task

By joining this pieces of information you should be able to write your source Script Component which can fetch data using any length dynamically constructed query.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of using a Script Component as a source, now I finally have a way to programmatically make my SSIS queries :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `select` statement to return a list of values that will include `('Frank', 'John', 'Markus', 'Tom')`. So your `select` would return :

```
Name
----------
Frank
John
Markus
Tom
```

Then, in SSIS, use a `Merge Join Component` (that will act as a `INNER JOIN`) instead of a where clause in your main query.

This is the cleaniest way to achieve what you want.